# crosstab query - dynamically derive column headings based on a related table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, crosstab

I tried:

```
TRANSFORM First([FirstName] & " " & [LastName] & " - " & [Status]) AS Name
SELECT qry_DateTemp.Date
FROM Customers RIGHT JOIN qry_DateTemp ON Customers.CustomerID = qry_DateTemp.CustomerID
GROUP BY qry_DateTemp.Date
PIVOT qry_DateTemp.RoomNumber In (select RoomNo from Room);
```

but when i provided the values in it...it worked perfectly

```
TRANSFORM First([FirstName] & " " & [LastName] & " - " & [Status]) AS Name
SELECT qry_DateTemp.Date
FROM Customers RIGHT JOIN qry_DateTemp ON Customers.CustomerID = qry_DateTemp.CustomerID
GROUP BY qry_DateTemp.Date
PIVOT qry_DateTemp.RoomNumber In (101,102,103,104,105,106,201,202);
```

What's wrong in my 1st query ?

Comment: is it not working = failing, or not working = giving wrong results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong in my 1st query ?

The only thing "wrong" with your query is that it simply uses syntax that Access SQL does not support. The IN clause following the PIVOT keyword only supports a static list of comma-separated column headings (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx#BM2.2.1)).

### Edit re: comments

As a workaround, you could convert the "guts" of your current Crosstab query into a regular Select query...

```sql
SELECT
    First([FirstName] & " " & [LastName] & " - " & [Status]) AS Name,
    qry_DateTemp.Date,
    First(qry_DateTemp.RoomNumber) AS RoomNo
FROM
    Customers 
    RIGHT JOIN 
    qry_DateTemp 
        ON Customers.CustomerID = qry_DateTemp.CustomerID
GROUP BY qry_DateTemp.Date
```

...and save that query as [qry_BookingsBase]. Let's imagine that said query returns...

```
Name                       Date        RoomNo
-------------------------  ----------  ------
Gord Thompson - confirmed  2013-10-15     101
Bob Loblaw - tentative     2013-10-16     102
Bob Loblaw - tentative     2013-10-17     102
```

We can create another saved query in Access named [qry_BookingsPadded] to "pad out" the data and ensure that there is at least one row for every room...

```sql
SELECT 
    qry_BookingsBase.[Name], 
    qry_BookingsBase.[Date],
    Room.[RoomNo] AS RoomNumber
FROM
    Room
    LEFT JOIN
    qry_BookingsBase
        ON Room.RoomNo = qry_BookingsBase.RoomNo
```

...returning...

```
Name                       Date        RoomNumber
-------------------------  ----------  ----------
Gord Thompson - confirmed  2013-10-15         101
Bob Loblaw - tentative     2013-10-17         102
Bob Loblaw - tentative     2013-10-16         102
                                              103
                                              104
                                              105
                                              106
                                              201
                                              202
```

Now you can just create a Crosstab query named [qry_BookingsCrosstab] against that "padded" query...

```sql
TRANSFORM First([Name]) AS FirstOfName
SELECT qry_BookingsPadded.Date
FROM qry_BookingsPadded
GROUP BY qry_BookingsPadded.Date
PIVOT qry_BookingsPadded.RoomNumber
```

...which returns...

```
Date        101                        102                     103  104  105  106  201  202
----------  -------------------------  ----------------------  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---

2013-10-15  Gord Thompson - confirmed                                                      
2013-10-16                             Bob Loblaw - tentative                              
2013-10-17                             Bob Loblaw - tentative
```

...and if that first row of all `Null` values is a problem then you could filter that out with

```sql
SELECT * FROM qry_BookingsCrosstab WHERE [Date] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: can i rearrange my 1st query to achieve desired result ?

Comment: thanks sir but i am getting warning when i executed your 1st query [qry_BookingsBase] you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'RoomNumber' as a part of aggregate function

Comment: @RahulSharma That first query was "air code". I've tweaked it a bit.

Comment: now everything is working :)
Thanks a ton sir i can't express in words... :)

Comment: Sir, can i achieve something like this...i tried full join in your 2nd query but not getting correct output in crosstab 3rd query....
http://www.4shared.com/photo/Wpy9BCxl/SnapShot__1_.html

Comment: @RahulSharma I think you may need to start a new question and explain more precisely what you want to accomplish.

Comment: i want something like this..
http://www.4shared.com/photo/Wpy9BCxl/SnapShot__1_.html

Your query output

http://www.4shared.com/photo/NB2PwNc6/SnapShot__2_.html

qry_DateTemp
http://www.4shared.com/photo/oQULWGHq/SnapShot__3_.html

Comment: okay sir but this problem is related to this question that's why i am not asking a new question ? check out screenshots when you are free, you will understand my problem better :)